# Is this a correct way to write a convenience constructor?

Tags: objective-c, constructor

I was reading more about the `instancetype` on Stack Overflow and now my question is:

For every convenience constructor that I write, do I need to have the corresponding one using `init`?

For example:

**RandomItem.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RandomItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;

+(instancetype)itemWithString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

**RandomItem.m**

```
#import "RandomItem.h"

@implementation RandomItem

+(instancetype)itemWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    RandomItem *anItem = [[self alloc] init];
    anItem.aString = string;
    return anItem;
}

@end
```

And compare this when using an `-initWithString:` constructor as well:

**RandomItem.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RandomItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;

-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string;
+(instancetype)itemWithString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

**RandomItem.m:**

```
#import "RandomItem.h"

@implementation RandomItem


-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.aString = string;
    }
    return self;
}


+(instancetype)itemWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithString:string];
}


@end
```

I suppose that both cases are fine, but I would like to hear your comments.

Thanks!

Comment: I've answered below, but wondering whether this question might be more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com, or maybe Stack Overflow?

Comment: Having said that, it probably falls within "Best practices and design pattern usage". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would prefer the second option because it makes it easier/less weird for subclasses to use and override alloc-init.

As a side node I would point to some reasons to reconsider user properties in your constructors.

- [Should I refer to self.property in the init method with ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056260/608157)
- [Friday Q&A 2009-11-27: Using Accessors in Init and Dealloc](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html)
- [Don’t Message self in Objective-C init (or dealloc)](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to match your initialisers with your class convenience constructor, especially in an ARC environment.

Take a look at the class documentation for [`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html) as an example from Apple — it defines three different convenience constructors, but no initialisers other than `-init`.

However, if you're not using ARC, there is a difference in memory management semantics: **class constructors are expected to return autoreleased objects** (and must be explicitly retained to transfer ownership to the caller). Or, more correctly, an object created by any method beginning with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` is owned by the caller (and thus any object that you are sending an `init...` message). See [Apple's memory management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).